# Dynamic python functions and exec confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary containing names as keys and class objects as values, like matchers_dict below but longer.

```py
matchers_dict = {'Positive': <spacy.matcher.Matcher at 0x1cd8d0d0518>,
 'Negative': <spacy.matcher.Matcher at 0x1cd8d0d0358>,
 'Angry': <spacy.matcher.Matcher at 0x1cd8bfee4a8>}
```

I need to create a function for each of the Matcher objects that looks like the following:

```py
def getter(doc):
   matcher = matches_dict['Positive']
   matches = my_matcher(doc)
   return (len(matches)
```

In order to pass it to this method

```
Doc.set_extension('Positive', None, getter=getter)
```

I don't want to create each getter function individually so I'm trying to create them dynamically using "exec" but I either get a string or none type. Here's what I have:

```py
def create_extensions(topic_dict):
    match_getters = []
    for name in matchers_dict.keys():
        match_getter = '''def match_getter(doc):
                                my_matcher = matchers['{}']
                                matches = my_matcher(doc)
                                return (len(matches)/len(doc)) *100'''.format(name)
        exec(match_getter)
        Doc.set_extension(name, getter=match_getter, force=True)
```

When I try to run the above I get an error showing that match_getter was passed as a string.

I've tried a few other things and looked at a number of exec related stackoverflow posts but continue to be stumped.

Note that the below doesn't work...

```py
def create_extensions(topic_dict):
    matchers = create_matchers(topic_dict)
    match_getters = []
    for name in matchers_dict.keys():
        def match_getter(doc):
              my_matcher = matchers[name]
              matches = my_matcher(doc)
              return (len(matches)/len(doc)) *100
        Doc.set_extension(name, None, getter=match_getter)
```

I end up with Doc extensions that all have the same value. It appears that only the last definition of match_getter is used.

I'm using Python 3.7.4

Comment: This doesn't work - see comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match_getter` is a string, that's what you defined it as. `exec` cannot modify local namespaces, so it was not overwritten by your dynamically executed `def match_getter(doc): ...` statement. In any case, it doesn't look like you even need to use exec here. You could usually just create the definition inside your other function, but since your function uses the free variables `matchers` and `name`, the correct solution is to use a function factory (unless of course, you *want* `name` to be the last item in the loop).

```
def getter_maker(matchers, name):
    def match_getter(doc):
        my_matcher = matchers[name]
        matches = my_matcher(doc)
        return (len(matches)/len(doc)) *100
    return match_getter


def create_extensions(topic_dict):
    matchers = create_matchers(topic_dict)
    match_getters = []
    for name in matchers.keys():
        match_getter = getter_maker(matchers, name)
        Doc.set_extension(name, getter=match_getter, force=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It returns whatever the result is for the last matcher in my list but for all matchers. In other words my Doc object has 10 different extensions with different names but the same value and 9 of the values are incorrect

Comment: @kalidurge no, it doesn't. That is **exactly** what the function factory is suppose to prevent. This is why you pass name explicitly, so name will always refer to the object passed in when the function is called in the loop. I even explained that you use this because `matchers` and `name` are free variables, and as we all know, Python uses late-binding, lexical closures to handle free variables.

Comment: OH, sorry, I read this too quickly. I see. You're 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to create a function using exec? Just define the function and use the variables.

```
def create_extensions(topic_dict):
    matchers = create_matchers(topic_dict)
    for name in matchers.keys():
        def match_getter(doc):
            matches = matchers[name](doc)
            return (len(matches)/len(doc)) *100
        Doc.set_extension(name, getter=match_getter, force=True)
```

You could even just create the function once and use `functools.partial`

```
def match_getter(name, doc):
    matches = matchers[name](doc)
    return (len(matches)/len(doc)) *100

def create_extensions(topic_dict):
    matchers = create_matchers(topic_dict)
    for name in matchers.keys():
        Doc.set_extension(name, getter=functools.partial(match_getter, name=name), force=True)
```

Comment: I edited to show function definition instead of using lambda

Comment: Yes, although I edited my comment, `name` is a free variable, so it is bound to the `name` at the end of the loop. a factory function should be used here.

Comment: What is `matchers`? OP doesn't show what it is in question only what `matchers_dict` is.

Comment: It's a local variable.

Comment: Correct although what does `create_matchers` return?

Comment: Okay, the first option I've tried already. It doesn't work. It returns whatever the result is for the last matcher in my list but for all matchers